# Building Rstudio using Qtcreator (Compile error)

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, rstudio

I'm trying to compile Rstudio by following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/RStudio-Development). After opening the file `rstudio/src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt` in qtcreator and running CMake, I get the build error

```
/home/nesau/Documents/GitHub/rstudio/src/cpp/tests/cpp/tests/vendor/catch.hpp
:1185:23:error: 'nullptr_t' is not a member of 'std'
std::string toString( std::nullptr_t );
                   ^
```

I've followed previous instructions such as installing the required dependencies (OS: Arch Linux). Some words of advice from someone who successfully managed to setup Rstudio in Qt-Creator would be appreciated - I'm open to using a different OS in a VM if need be - I'm just not sure why I can't compile Rstudio (the GitHub wiki isn't very detailed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to C++11 mode. Add `-std=c++11` to your `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.